# Correct wording of an exercise about showing that a map is an epic-mono factorization of $2^f$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Consider the following question, taken from Arbib and Manes' *Arrows, structures and functors* text:

**Question:** Prove that if $(e,m)$ is an epi-mono factorization of $f$ then $(2^m, 2^e)$ is an epi-mono factorization of $2^f$.

The relevant definition, proposition and exercises which the above question is based on are as follows:

> **Definition:**  We say that the pair $(e, m)$ epi-mono factorization of the map $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ if $e$ is an epimorphism and $m$ is a monomorphism such that $f = m \circ e$.
> [image]
>
> **Proposition:**  Epi-mono factorizations are unique up to isomorphism in the sense that if $(e', m')$ is an epi-mono factorization
>
> [image]
>
> of a given map $f \colon A \rightarrow B$, then there is an isomorphism $\phi$ such that the above diagram commutes.
>
> Exercise: Let $2^{A}$ denote the power set of all subsets of $A$.  Given $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ define $2^{f} \colon 2^{B} \rightarrow 2^{A}$ by $2^{f}(S) = f^{-1}(S) = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in S \subset B\}$. Prove that $f$ is onto iff $2^{f}$ is one-to-one.

What I would like to know is that if the question is worded correctly. Specifically, whether the notation $(2^m, 2^e)$ is correct?  Should it not be $(2^e, 2^m)$ instead? Or, since, $(e, m)$ means there are the following mappings:
$f \colon A \rightarrow B$, $e \colon A \rightarrow f(A)$ and $m \colon f(A) \subset B \rightarrow B$. Then the question is asking about the reversal of arrows in the $(e, m)$ commutative diagram, meaning: $2^f(S) \colon S \rightarrow f^{-1}(S)$, where $S \subset B$.  I am thinking the wording of the question might be about reversing all the arrows. Hence $(2^m, 2^e)$ would be $2^f(S) \colon S \rightarrow f^{-1}(S)$, $2^m(S) \colon S \rightarrow f(S)$ and $2^e(S) \colon f(S) \rightarrow f^{-1}(S)$. However, I am also not sure how to write out the maps $2^e(S)$ and $2^f(S)$ in set builder notations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this in $\mathbf{Set}$ or in a general category with (at least some) power objects and epi-mono factorizations?  (From the exercise not saying it's concentrating on the case of $\mathbf{Set}$, I'm guessing the former, but it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: But in any case, the exercise you quote suggests that if $(e,m)$ is an epi-mono factorization, then $2^e$ is mono (but there are examples where $2^e$ is not epi) so it should go in the mono slot of the factorization of $2^f$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler $f:A\rightarrow B$, $e:A\rightarrow f(A)$ and $m:f(A)\subset B\rightarrow B$.  Also, since $2^f(S):S\rightarrow F^{-1}(S)$, where $S\subset B$.  I am thinking the wording of the question might be about reversing all the arrows.  Hence $(2^m,2^e)$ would be $2^f(S):S\rightarrow f^{-1}(S)$, $2^m(S):S\rightarrow f(S)$ and $2^e(S):f(S)\rightarrow f^{-1}(S)$

Comment: @DanielSchepler I edited the question to be a bit clearer about what my points of confusions.

Comment: Yes, often it's more useful to work with the contravariant version of the powerset functor (which operates on morphisms by taking inverse images as you say) than the covariant version of the powerset functor (which operates on morphisms by taking direct images).  And from the statement of the problem, the author is almost certainly working with the contravariant version of the powerset functor.

Comment: @DanielSchepler is the way I defined my arrow reversing map correctly?  I am just not sure since I am still very new to category theory. I further edit my post to add the relevant commutative diagram pic associated to the cited definition.

Comment: Your notation is not quite right, Seth: you're confusing the domain and codomain of $2^f$ with its inputs and outputs. We should write $2^f:2^B\to 2^A$ with $2^f(S)=f^{-1}(S).$ Most importantly, $2^f(S)$ is *not a function,* but a *set.* It would also be less confusing if you just wrote $e:A\to C, m:C\to B.$ Then we have $2^m:2^B\to 2^C,2^e:2^C\to 2^A.$

Comment: @KevinArlin but $(2^m, 2^e)$ is still referring to arrow reversing?  My understanding is that if $(2^m, 2^e)$ is the reversal of $(2^e, 2^m)$, then it is like going in the direction of the opposite category.  Meaning epimorphism become monomorphism and vice versa.  Also, the set $C$ you are referring to, do you mean $C=f(A)$?

Comment: Yes, $C=f(A).$ And yes, I'm using the arrow-reversing $2^{(-)}$ functor, as you can see by the domain and codomains I wrote. You need to prove directly that $2^m$ is epi and $2^e$ is mono, not just use abstract properties of opposite categories, since $2^m$ is not merely $m$ viewed in the opposite category of sets.

Comment: @KevinArlin actually. i think i made a mistake or neglect a minor point, for the case of arrow reversing, should it be $C^{op}=f(S)$?.  I am using $C^{op}$ to distinguish it from $C$.

Comment: Don't do anything in the opposite category. If $f:A\to B$ then $2^f:2^B\to 2^A,$ *in the category of sets*! It's unnecessary confusing to think about this, for instance, as $2^f:(2^A)^{\mathrm{op}}\to (2^B)^{\mathrm{op}}.$

Comment: The answer to your double question ("What I would like to know is that if the question is worded correctly. Specifically, whether the notation $(2^m,2^e)$ is correct") is simply: yes and yes. And everything you wrote after them is not correct, as explained in detail by Kevin Arlin.

Comment: Are you sure they wrote $$f^{-1}(S) = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in S \subset B\}?$$  It should rather be $f^{-1}(S) = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in S\},$ for all $S\subset B.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I copied the question verbatium.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for clarifying it for me.   I just think that the notation $2^f(S)=f^{-1}(S)$ is confusing.  There are two different notations for the inverse image, and one of them when in proving the question:   "$f$ is onto iff $2^f$ is one to one.", that $2^f(S)$ is treated as if it is in function notation.  Because the argument  of $2^f()$ should be an element of set $S\subset B$ or could it consists of subsets of $B$.

Comment: Re-read Kevin's comment above beginning with "Your notation is not quite right, Seth". $2^f$ is a function from $2^B$ to $2^A,$ so its argument is not "an element of set $S\subset B$"; it is an (varying) element $S$ of $2^B,$ i.e. subset $S$ of $B.$